# Hibernate NamedQuery in abstract class

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have 20 classes that inherite from **AbstractEntity**, and all of them needs to have the same NamedQueries, as an example let's take a simple one:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Bootle.FIND_BY_ID, query = //
        "SELECT entity FROM " + Bootle.ENTITY_NAME + " entity " + 
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH entity.value val " + 
        "..." +
        "WHERE entity.id = :pIds AND entity.relationable = :pBoolean")
```

And I wish I could move these queries to the AbstractEntity, however then I am not able to determine EntityName for hibernate. Ideal solution would be to have it somehow like:

```
@NamedQuery(name = BaseDAO.FIND_BY_ID, query = //
            "SELECT entity FROM " + AbstractEntity.ENTITY_NAME + " entity " + 
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH entity.value val " + 
            "..." +
            "WHERE entity.id = :pIds AND entity.relationable = :pBoolean")
```

But above example won't work. Can Hibernate by itself give a proper entite names when I query this method?

Example of the current query call:

```
getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(BaseDAO.FIND_BY_ID)
                .setParameter("pId", 201L)
                .setParameter("pBoolean", false);
```

Comment: Why reinvent https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object- ?

Comment: @Smutje I just simplified (a bit too much) one of the queries, real queries are much more complex, with multiple LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH

Comment: Values in annotation is static, defined at compile time. You cannot have a dynamic value in you namedQuery. You will need tool like Spring data to automatize Query creation. imho, it is better to keep clean real litteral queries than trying to generate them in a process that is not the nominal usage.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions

> To avoid stating the actual entity name in the query string of a
>   @Query annotation, you can use the **#{#entityName}** variable.
>
> The entityName can be customized by using the @Entity annotation.
>   Customizations in orm.xml are not supported for the SpEL expressions.
>   Of course, you could have just used User in the query declaration
>   directly, but that would require you to change the query as well. The
>   reference to #entityName picks up potential future remappings of the
>   User class to a different entity name (for example, by using
>   @Entity(name = "MyUser").
>
> Another use case for the #{#entityName} expression in a query string
>   is if you want to define a generic repository interface with
>   specialized repository interfaces for a concrete domain type. To not
>   repeat the definition of custom query methods on the concrete
>   interfaces, you can use the entity name expression in the query string
>   of the @Query annotation in the generic repository interface.

Example

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractMappedType {
  …
  String attribute
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteType extends AbstractMappedType { … }

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MappedTypeRepository<T extends AbstractMappedType>
  extends Repository<T, Long> {

  @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where t.attribute = ?1")
  List<T> findAllByAttribute(String attribute);
}

public interface ConcreteRepository
  extends MappedTypeRepository<ConcreteType> { … }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only possible when using Spring, which is not a case in here